# Is there a free way to send/receive text messages from a RoR web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms

I've being doing extensive research but having a hard time finding a cost effective answer. I'm creating a RoR application that requires texts to be sent out occasionally to a customer and for that customer to be able to reply, where my application could then put that reply into a database for further processing. Does anyone have experience with this that may be able to help? Thank you.

Comment: @Pavan I believe ActionMailer is only useful for sending emails. Not sending/receiving text messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `twilio` api to implement this but it's only free for development. For production it's not free. More info here http://www.twilio.com/sms

Comment: Yeah, Twilio seems to be the most popular but at .75 cents per message it's way out of the price point we can hit. I was hoping for alternatives.

Comment: Go through this once http://www.intridea.com/blog/2008/3/30/sms-fu-quickly-easily-send-text-messages

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but that requires me to know the carrier of the number right?